# How can I specify a path on a Mac

Tags: python, macos, python-2.7, path

I'm using Python 2.7.2. and I want to open and use a dictionary I created in my shell. My problem is, when I try to import this dictionary into my shell it can't find the file because python is just looking into the 'my documents' folder.

My question is, how can I navigate to the correct folder (just one folder further in 'my documents' folder.

I am using a Macintosh.

Answer (score 1):

You can add custom path to your script as:

```
import sys
sys.path.append('/Users/username/')
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way is to set the PYTHONPATH environment variable to /User/username in your shell. Since you know about your shell, I expect that you already know how to edit your shell resource script. You could also add it to your .profile file in which case it should be available even if you change which shell you happen to be using.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to "hardwire" the system path, but want to use a relative folder, you could get the name of the working directory and add your subdirectory to that...

```
subdirname = 'myfolder'
curdir = os.getcwd()
newdir = os.path.join(curdir,subdirname)
sys.path.append(newdir)
```